# How to change color in Tree View odoo using two function

Tags: xml, odoo-8

I would like to know how to change the color of line in Tree View using two function.
I already using like this :

```html
<tree string="Keep Lines" colors="red:is_move==False">
```

I want to include two function on there like :
is_move==False and is_expired==True
How to include that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, just add "and" on there, it will be like :

```html
<tree string="Keep Lines" colors="red:is_move==False and is_expired==True">
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, try this:

```
<tree string="Keep Lines" colors="red:is_move==False;is_expired==True">
```

In .xml

```
<, >, <=, >= is not supported. 
So we need to use &lt;, &gt;, &lt;=, and &gt;=.
```